# How to bulkify this Apex code?

Tags: apex, bulkification

I wrote the following code, but I know that it is not properly bulkified. I have tried to bulkify it, but facing some issues. Please guide me on how to bulkify this code, so that I can use it as reference in the future.

```
public class LeadInsertTriggerHandler {

public static void AfterInsert(List<Lead> lstLeads)
{
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [select MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted = true limit 1];
    List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

    for (Lead lead: lstLeads) {
        if (!lead.isConverted) {
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();

            lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
            lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);

            List<account> obj_account = [select id from account where 
                                         Email_and_SiteID__c= :lead.Email_and_SiteID__c];
            if(obj_account.size()>0)
            {
                lc.setAccountId(obj_account[0].id);
            }
                leadConverts.add(lc);
            }
            }

            if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: one quick question since you will be doing convert to lead from UI (because then only isconvert checkbox will be true) and after that from trigger again doing convert. Doesn't make sense. It will throw error like lead already converted in trigger.

Comment: @RatanPaul I am trying to autoconvert all the leads once they are inserted. If there is an existing account,  and if some of the accounts fields are empty, I am copying the data from Lead to Account

Comment: Ahh my mis. I didn't see `!lead.isConverted` not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to move the query outside the loop. I call this the aggregate-query-update pattern, since we "aggregate" values into a collection, "query" for those values, and then perform some type of "update" (in this case, a lead conversion).

```
Map<String, Id> emailSiteMap = new Map<String, Account>();
// Filtering reduces code; we only check for converted leads once.
Lead[] leadsToProcess = new Lead[0];
for(Lead record: lstLeads) {
  if(!record.isConverted) {
    leadsToProcess.add(record);
  }
}
// Saves two queries minimum
if(leadsToProcess.isEmpty()) {
  return;
}
LeadStatus convertStatus = [select MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted = true limit 1];
List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
// Aggregate values to query
for(Lead record: leadsToProcess) {
  emailSiteMap.put(record.Email_and_SiteId__c, null);
}
// Query for those values
for(Account record: [SELECT Email_and_SiteId__c FROM Account WHERE Email_and_SiteId__c = :emailSiteMap.keySet()]) {
  emailSiteMap.put(record.Email_and_SiteId__c, record.Id);
}
// Prepare to update
for(Lead record: leadsToProcess) {
  Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
  lc.setLeadId(record.Id);
  lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
  lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE);
  Id accountId = emailSiteMap.get(record.Email_and_SiteId__c);
  if(accountId != null) {
    lc.setAccountId();
  }
  leadConverts.add(lc);
}
// And perform DML operation.
Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Through your code, I am able to understand bulkification. But when I execute that code, It is creating a new account. Email_and_SiteId__c is a custom formula field on both my account and lead objects. It's combination of Email+SiteID. So If I convert a lead with the same Email_and_SiteID field, then it should not create a new account, but it should just copy the data into empty fields. where should I add that functionality in your code exactly. Tried to do that, but failed. So asking for help

Comment: @Venkata The results are case sensitive and must match exactly. Without seeing your data, I can't tell you why it's going wrong, but you might try writing a unit test and check.